# semicolon in fall through of switch case statement

Tags: javascript, java, c#, c++, c

Is there any significance to adding a semicolon in the case statement that is part of a fall-through ? I see that the fall-through works as expected and guess the semicolon is interpreted as an empty statement. But are there pros/cons to having the semicolon ? Is there a certain best practice that is recommended ? In the javascript example below, see the semicolon in the first case statement.

```
    switch(a) {
        case 2:;
        case 3: alert('hello'); break;
        default: alert('default hello');
    }
```

I am also interested in knowing about the best practices related to the above in C, C++ and Java. I also saw some documentation that C# throws a compilation error if a case statement part of a fall-through has a statement. Will an empty statement like the above trigger an error in C#?

Comment: I have never seen it previously. And see no point in having it.

Comment: A five language question!, except it is strange `C` nor `C++` code to use such wide character constants.

Comment: You don't need a semi colon in Java, it would just fall through

Comment: In C a semicolon marks the end of a code block/statement, even if there is nothing in it. I would be significant following an `if()` or `while()` or `for()`.

Comment: Best C practice: add a comment on cases that intentionally fall through to the next case. `case 2:; // fall through`.

Comment: It's more confusing if you like that sort of thing.

Comment: Probably done by someone with bash scripting habits - No, he would have added ";;"

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not make any difference.

I recommend you not to use it since it makes the code less clear, in my opinion.

In C# it's an error though.
D does not allow `;` as an empty statement too, you have to use `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

`;` does nothing for you in C, C++, and Java. If you don't need it, don't use it. But do throw future readers of your code a bone if you are implementing [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) or a variant and leave them "fall through" or "no break" comments.

In C#

```
switch(a) {
    case 2:;
    case 3: Console.WriteLine("hello"); break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("default hello");
}
```

prevents cases 2 and 3 executing the same code by interrupting the little bit of fall through C# does allow.

```
switch(a) {
    case 2:
    case 3: Console.WriteLine("hello"); break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("default hello"); break;
}
```

Would be valid with cases 2 and 3 executing the same code.

Answer (score 0):

> best practice

Is usually not to use an empty statement.

> Will an empty statement like the above trigger an error in C#?

Yes.

Answer (score -1):

Syntactically it's the same

It's bound to confuse someone though so I'd recommend against using it